# why can't I redirect after successful login?

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to access a welcome page after login using

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successForwardUrl("/welcome")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

My `UserDetailsService` is:

```
@Service(value = "customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userService.findByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            logger.error("User with email" + email + " not found.");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Oops! User not found with username: " + email);
        } else {
            logger.info("User {} successfully logged", user.getUsername());
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), getAuthorities(user));
        }
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        for (UserProfile userProfile : user.getUserProfileSet()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + userProfile.getType()));
        }

        return authorities;
    }
}
```

The relevant bits of the controllers are:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Principal principal) {

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("getWelcome is executed");
        System.out.println(principal);
    }
    return principal == null ? "homeNotSignedIn" : "welcome";
}

@GetMapping("/login")
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    if (error != null)
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

    if (logout != null)
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> LOGOUT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

    return "login";
}

@GetMapping("/welcome")
public String welcome(Model model) {
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WELCOME <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
    return "welcome";
}
```

My `pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ie.gtludwig.pa</groupId>
<artifactId>pa</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>PA</name>
<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>engine</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <!-- JAVA -->
    <version.java>1.8</version.java>
    <java.version>${version.java}</java.version>
    <jdk.version>${version.java}</jdk.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>${version.java}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>${version.java}</maven.compiler.source>
    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
     <!-- External Dependency Versions -->
    <spring-boot.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <jedis.version>2.9.1</jedis.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.11.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.3.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    <flyway.version>5.2.0</flyway.version>
    <mysql.version>8.0.16</mysql.version>
    <h2database.version>1.4.199</h2database.version>
    <sendgrid-java.version>4.3.0</sendgrid-java.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.7</commons-lang3.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--WEB-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--SECURITY-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!--OPERATIONS-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>


     <!--SERVER-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--DATABASE-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--TEST DATABASE FOR TESTING PROCESSES AND RULES IN-MEMORY-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2database.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
           <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!--EMAIL-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sendgrid/sendgrid-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>${sendgrid-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--DEV/TEST-->
    <!--DEV TOOLS CONFLICT WITH JREBEL - DISABLE THIS IF JREBEL IS BEING USED -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Resource plugin to enable expanding properties from this file so that they can be exposed by the zone (E.g. @project.version@) -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <!--font/binary files must be excluded from filtering or they will be corrupted-->
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                </delimiters>
                <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <!-- Add our project version to the manifest file -->
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <description>${project.description}</description>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <attachClasses>false</attachClasses>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>external</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

What happens is:

When I access `localhost:8080/core` I get the correct `homeNotSignedIn` page, but there is no CSS or JS loaded from `/resources/**`.
I click a login redirection link to the login page (again without CSS or JS) and **CAN** login.
The logged username is displayed to the console, so the `customUserDetailsService` seems to be working alright, but I don't get redirected to `/welcome`.
At this point, I can only logout by typing `/logout` to the URL and it works and sends me to `homeNotSignedIn`.

I have been going back and forth at this and I can't seem to get it done.

What am I missing?

I have been going back and forth at this and I can't seem to get it done.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
I managed to load CSS and JS by changing:

`.antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()`

to:

`.antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll()`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `successForwardUrl` you will be forwarded to the given URL, but not redirected.
That means that the URL in your browser will not change, however it will display the HTML in your `welcome.html`.

If you would like to redirect, you can use `defaultSuccessUrl` as mentioned on the [spring-security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html#defaultSuccessUrl-java.lang.String-boolean-).
Then your security configuration would look like this.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}
```